# How can I access specific one file from resource mapping in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the following servlet mapping present -

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/resources/js/" />
```

**Observation:** 
If any web request starts with the **/js** request path, then it will be mapped to the resources directory, and the /** symbol indicates the recursive look for any resource files underneath the base resource directory. Here I can access **js/test.js, js/test2.js**

**Requirement :** 
   I want to access only one specific file(**js/test.js**). How can I access specific one file(**js/test.js**) not all files which present into **/resources/js** location.

Can I use below servlet mapping :::

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/test.js" location="/resources/js/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add this line

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/resources/js/" />
```

Spring will add a filter rule which says

Whenever any URL with `/js/**` is fired, spring look for it recursively in `/resources/js/` folder.

When you add following configuration

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/test.js" location="/resources/js/" />
```

Only URL with `/js/test.js` will be looked in `/resources/js/` folder.

Please be mindful that any other request eg `/js/jquery` or `js/abc` will not be filtered.

Comment: If location /resources/js/ has other js files, I can access those by url js/test1.js, js/test2.js like js/test.js. Is there any filter where I can access only js/test.js not js/test1.js?

Comment: Are you using Spring Security?

Comment: why should we use /** in mapping?